# Error when calling webservice from silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, soap

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI
>   'http://localhost:42083/Services/MyService.asmx'. This could be due to
>   attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper
>   cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP
>   services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish
>   a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP
>   headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal
>   types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details.

And the most peculiar thing about is that before it worked just fine,  but when I changed just
a little thing in a stored procedure it throws this exception. That's weird! I'm getting a little more suspect against SOAP services for now. Anybody who has any ideas?

Comment: Can you put up a fiddler session to see if the change you've made did not end up trying to contact external endpoints? And recheck your cross-domain policy files. Maybe they disappeared because some re-compilation action ...

Comment: I can't seem to find any crossdomain.xml file. Maybe I should create one manually?

Comment: I got tired of this errors. I'm switching to do webclient and parsing xml files instead. Much more low level but a lot more reliable I think.

Comment: When I put the Services folder with the webservice and the clientaccesspolicy file under the ClientBin folder it all worked like a charm. ??? I thought of serving it like a relative source. Seems like it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read you comment, please make sure you have deployed a cross-domain policy file. Tim has a great blog about it: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx. It is really an essential asset to obtain when starting SL to server communication.

Hope that helps.